# Submit div not appearing at the bottom

Tags: css, html

I am not able to place the submit button at the bottom of the Webpage. I have placed the listDiv and DropDwnDiv inline to each other. If i remove the float left and float right property then i see that submit button comes at the bottom. What i am missing here? Following is my First part of  code. Any kind of input/feedback is really appreciated. Dividing my code into two parts head and body, as stack-overflow doesn't let me post the code if the contents of the post are more code and less text.

```
 h1 {
  padding : 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  width: 1000px;
  background: grey;
  font-size: 40;
  font-family: times-roman;
  margin:70px;
 }
    p {
     color:black;
     text-align:center;
    }

   ol {
    background:#ff9999;
    width: 1000px;
    padding : 40px;
    margin : 70px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20;
    }

    #MainDiv {
      background: grey;
      padding: 40px;
      margin: 70px;
      font-size:20;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 500px;
    }

  #UnameDiv {
      background: grey;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      font-size:20;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #textareaDiv {
      background: grey;
      display : block;
      text-align:center;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

   #listDiv {
      float: right;
      background:grey;
      font-size: 15;
      padding: 30px;
      margin-top: 70px;
      margin-right: 70px;
    }

    #DropDwnDiv {
      float : left;
      background:grey;
      font-size: 15;
      padding: 30px;
      margin-top: 70px;
      margin-left: 70px;
    }

    #subDiv {
      background:grey;
      float: initial;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display:block;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: Hold it right there ! Do not paste raw code into comments. It's very hard to read. Edit your question with the code. Do not use `float` as it gets elements out of their normal flow and you end up with this kind of mess. Use flex instead

Comment: do you want to align listDiv & DropDwnDiv in the same row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this style to the paragraph that contains the submit button.

```html
<p style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these coding style :

1. input tag is a self closing tag
2. when ever you are using `float:***`, always try to clear it `clear: both`
3. Don't use p tag always

Use `<br style="clear: both;" />` before the submit button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  h1 {
  padding : 10px 40px 10px 40px;
  width: 1000px;
  background: grey;
  font-size: 40;
  font-family: times-roman;
  margin:70px;
 }
    p {
     color:black;
     text-align:center;
    }

   ol {
    background:#ff9999;
    width: 1000px;
    padding : 40px;
    margin : 70px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20;
    }

    #MainDiv {
      background: grey;
      padding: 40px;
      margin: 70px;
      font-size:20;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    #UnameDiv {
      background: grey;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      font-size:20;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #textareaDiv {
      background: grey;
      display : block;
      text-align:center;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

   #listDiv {
      float: right;
      background:grey;
      font-size: 15;
      padding: 30px;
      margin-top: 70px;
      margin-right: 70px;
    }
    #DropDwnDiv {
      float : left;
      background:grey;
      font-size: 15;
      padding: 30px;
      margin-top: 70px;
      margin-left: 70px;
    }

    #subDiv {
      background:grey;
      float: initial;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display:block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="test">
    <p> THIS IS 
        <strong>MY</strong> WEBPAGE 
    </p>
</h1>
<ol>
    <li> 'ZX14R'</li>
    <li>'MULTISTRADA 1200S'</li>
    <li>'TRIUMP TIGER 1200'</li>
</ol>
<div id='MainDiv'>
    <form action="xyz.php", method="get">
        <div id='UnameDiv'>
            <p> 
             USERNAME:- <input type="label" placeholder='ENTER USERNAME' name="label" />
            </p>
            <p> 
             PASSWORD:- <input type="password" value='*****' name="passwd" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id='textareaDiv'>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="35" placeholder= "ENTER DESCRIPTION HERE"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id='DropDwnDiv'>
            <p>
                <b> WHICH CITY YOU BELONG TO</b>
            </p>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="BANGALORE" checked/>BANGALORE
            <br>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="MUMBAI"/>MUMBAI
                <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="DELHI"/>DELHI
        </div>
        <div id='ListDiv'>
                <b>SELECT YOUR FAV CINEMA TYPE</b>
            <select>
                <option> 'PVR CINEMAS'</option>
                <option> 'INOX CINEMAS' </option>
                <option>'FAME CINEMAS'</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br style="clear: both;" />
        <div id='subDiv'>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </div>
       </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May i ask how do you manage to get the entire code in comment section?